# reactjs, comparison using array from document

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a document being passed into a function which has the format 
`0:{username:"test", name:"TestName"}`
and everything prints in the console properly, but when I try to access `userName` from it I get an undefined error.

My code currently:

```
const newuserDocs = result.docs;         

console.log(newuserDocs);

if(this.newUserDocs.username === "test"){
  console.log('THE USERNAME IS GOOD');
}
```

I know that newUserDocs is set because I can dump it in the console or elsewhere just fine but trying to do this comparison is failing at the `.username` portion

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that keyword `this` is ambigous, as soon as `newuserDocs` is defined as variable you can access is without `this.` portion as soon as context for `this` is unclear in your example:

```
if(this.newUserDocs.username === "test"){
  console.log('THE USERNAME IS GOOD');
}
```

UPD: js is case sensitive. Your variable is called `newuserDocs` (lower-case U) and then your access it by `newUserDocs` (upper-case U). Try newuserDocs.username

Comment: If i try just as ```newUserDocs.username``` then it says ```newUserDocs``` is undefined

Comment: js is case sensitive. Your variable is called newuserDocs (lower-case U) and then your access it by newUserDocs (upper-case U). Try `newuserDocs.username`

Comment: oh wow, not sure how I missed that. however, I changed it and it still says 'cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: Wait, I got it to clear the error due to the same issue with userName. But it's not printing my console even though the username matches

Comment: Hmm, And the last idea accoding to your data format, `newuserDocs[0].username`

Comment: Ah YES, that got it!! Thanks so much for the extra eyes. I've been looking at this project for too long with no sleep haha

Answer (score 1):

I run this, it works perfect. You missed:

1. You have to approach the variable without use `this.`.
2. The spelling of the const.

   ```
   const newuserDocs = {username:"test", name:"TestName"};

   console.log(newuserDocs);

   if(newuserDocs.username === "test"){
     console.log('THE USERNAME IS GOOD');
   }
   ```

[image]

I hope it helps you.